# C# SSL Implementation Issues

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, mono

I'm currently trying to add SSL to a project that I'm working on so I checked MSDN for an SSL stream example server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.security.sslstream I've ran it and it runs but when a client connects it throws this error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The client stopped the handshake.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslServerStream.OnNegotiateHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Whats happening? Also why does it only require the certificate but not the private key file? SSL just doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The private key is supplied through the certificate object, see `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey`. If you have a certificate file and a separate private key file, I think you have to load the private key manually and assign it to the certificate's `PrivateKey` property.

Comment: +1, as requiring a certificate for private/public keys is a .NET common practice, http://www.lextm.com/2012/02/simple-publicprivate-key-signing-sample.html

Comment: .NET's cryptography *is* certificate-centric, especially in the import/export department. That's why BouncyCastle is so popular.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy I'm having an issue finding where I import the private key.

Comment: That depends on what container (file, smart card, machine/user key store etc.) is your private key (and certificate) stored in. First, take a look at `X509Certificate2` constructors, especially those that take an `X509KeyStorageFlags` argument, and see whether your case falls under one of the options there. Then look at the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class, and finally look at BouncyCastle or other similar cryptography libraries.